# What using statement must be added to use the Backup class in c#

Tags: c#

I want to use the `Backup` class to make a backup of my database.

`Backup backup =new Backup();`

However, I do not know what namespace this class is found in.

---

I added Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended.dll And Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll

Now its Work !

Thanks all

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. Please explain it,

Comment: He's asking what namespace is the `Backup` class found in.

Comment: Have you tried asking google "c# backup class"? That's the very first result I'm getting: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.backup.aspx (don't forget to add the appropriate reference, or `using` won't work)

Comment: You can always just right click the class and click 'Resolve' and the correct using statement will be added for you assuming you have the reference to it in your project

Comment: @DGibbs I don't think `Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo` is a reference you'll find in many projects, let alone brand-new ones. So long as he doesn't know the proper Namespace, he won't get far with VS's Resolve feature in this particular case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The namespace for the `Backup` class is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.backup(v=sql.90).aspx

`Namespace: Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo`

`Assembly: Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo (in microsoft.sqlserver.smo.dll)`

Based on your comment of the `using` statement not working you have to properly add the `.dll` reference.  `Project->Add Reference` in the menu toolbar in vs.net.

Comment: @AliJockar - Did you add the .dll reference?

Comment: @AliJockar You need to add the proper reference, or `using` won't work, see my comment on your question.

Comment: @AliJockar, right click on the project references, add reference to the dlll, it is usually present at `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\SDK\Assemblies`

Comment: yes i added microsoft.sqlserver.smo.dll,microsoft.sqlserver.ConnectionInfo and microsoft.sqlserver.SqlEnum to my project  Reference

Comment: private void BackupDb()
        {
            dbName = ((Database)cmbBackupDb.SelectedItem).Name;
            Backup dbBackup = new Backup();
            

            try
            {
                dbBackup.Action = BackupActionType.Database;
                dbBackup.Database = dbName; .........